# connect points within position_dodged factor x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I'm trying to add significance annotations to an `errorbar plot` with a factor x-axis and dodged groups within each level of the `x-axis`. It is a similar but NOT identical use case to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122030/connect-points-within-x-values-for-ggplot2)

My base errorbar plot is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

pres_prob_pd = structure(list(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), labels = c(`1` = 1, 
`2` = 2, `3` = 3)), predicted = c(0.571584427222816, 0.712630712634987, 
0.156061969566517, 0.0162388386564817, 0.0371877245103279, 0.0165022541901018, 
0.131528946944238, 0.35927812866896, 0.0708662221985375), std.error = c(0.355802875027348, 
0.471253661425626, 0.457109887762665, 0.352871728451576, 0.442646879181155, 
0.425913568532558, 0.376552208691762, 0.48178172708116, 0.451758041335245
), conf.low = c(0.399141779923204, 0.496138837620712, 0.0701919316506831, 
0.00819832576725402, 0.0159620304815404, 0.00722904089045731, 
0.0675129352870401, 0.17905347369819, 0.030504893442457), conf.high = c(0.728233665534388, 
0.861980236164486, 0.311759350126477, 0.031911364587827, 0.0842227723261319, 
0.0372248587668487, 0.240584344249407, 0.590437963881823, 0.156035177669385
), group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("certain", 
"neutral", "uncertain"), class = "factor"), group_col = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("certain", "neutral", 
"uncertain"), class = "factor"), language = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("english", "dutch", "german"
), class = "factor"), top = c(0.861980236164486, 0.861980236164486, 
0.861980236164486, 0.0842227723261319, 0.0842227723261319, 0.0842227723261319, 
0.590437963881823, 0.590437963881823, 0.590437963881823)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), groups = structure(list(language = structure(1:3, .Label = c("english", 
"dutch", "german"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    4:6, 1:3, 7:9), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#dodge
pd = position_dodge(.75)

#plot
p = ggplot(pres_prob_pd,aes(x=language,y=predicted,color=group,shape=group)) +
  geom_point(position=pd,size=2) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=conf.high,ymin=conf.low),width=.125,position=pd)
p
```

[image]

What I want to do is annotate the plot such that the contrasts between `group` within each level of `language` are annotated for significance. I've plotted points representing the relevant contrasts and (toy) sig. annotations as follows:

```
#bump function
f = function(x){
  v = c()
  bump=0.025
  constant = 0
  for(i in x){
    v = c(v,i+constant+bump)
    bump = bump + 0.075
  }
  v
}

#create contrasts
combs = data.frame(gtools::combinations(3, 2, v=c("certain", "neutral", "uncertain"), set=F, repeats.allowed=F)) %>%
  mutate(contrast=c("cont_1","cont_2","cont_3"))
combs = rbind(combs %>% mutate(language = 'english'),
              combs %>% mutate(language='dutch'),
              combs %>% mutate(language = "german")) %>%
  left_join(select(pres_prob_pd,language:top)%>%distinct(),by='language') %>%
  group_by(language) 

#long transform and calc y_pos
combs_long = mutate(combs,y_pos=f(top)) %>% gather(long, probability, X1:X2, factor_key=TRUE) %>% mutate(language=factor(language,levels=c("english","dutch","german"))) %>% 
  arrange(language,contrast)

#back to wide
combs_wide =combs_long %>% spread(long,probability) 
combs_wide$p = rep(c('***',"*","ns"),3)

#plot
p + 
      geom_point(data=combs_long,
               aes(x = language,
                   color=probability,
                   shape=probability,
                 y=y_pos),
               inherit.aes = T,
               position=pd,
               size=2) +
    geom_text(data=combs_wide,
               aes(x=language,
                   label=p,
                  y=y_pos+.025,
                  group=X1),
              color='black',
              position=position_dodge(.75),
              inherit.aes = F)
```

[image]

What I am failing to achieve is plotting a line connecting each of the contrasts of `group` within each level of `language`, as is standard when annotating significant group-wise differences. Any help much appreciated!